# Express the idea of something being suitable for something: "a Baby friendly hotel"

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I'm just wondering how I can use Japanese to express the idea of something being suitable for something.

In my specific case, I was trying to express to a friend that I found a "baby friendly" hotel. I can't seem to find any grammar guides on how to express the concept of something being suitable for babies.

I already know 子供向け (intended for children), but I don't think that works for this situation.

How could someone say "a [noun] friendly [noun]"

e.g. a dog friendly shopping mall.

e.g. a train service suitable for children.

Thanks!

Comment: https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e3%83%9a%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e9%80%a3%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a7&ref=wl

Comment: https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=kid-friendly

Answer (score 2):

One way to express this could be...

```
＿＿＿歓迎{かんげい}の＿＿＿
```

- **赤{あか}ちゃん歓迎の**ホテル

  a **baby-friendly** hotel
- **ワンちゃん歓迎の**マンション

  a **dog-friendly** apartment

Also, in the case of something being suitable for babies and small children, the word ファミリー is often used.

ファミリーホテル、ファミリー旅行プラン

[image]